# removeMouseListener method not working

Tags: java, swing

The removeMouseListener is not working: if I click on the old JLabel it is still adding to the variable score. Every time the time lapse is passed the old object should have `mouseListener` removed and the new one should be the only one with it.

```
Timer picTimer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener(){

            int oldrr=0;
            int oldrc=0 ;
            final int[] score = {0};
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                MouseAdapter act = new MouseAdapter(){

                    @Override public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){

                        score[0]++;
                        lblTimer.setText(String.valueOf(score[0]));

                      }
                    };
                arrayWM[oldrr][oldrc].removeMouseListener(act);
                arrayWM[oldrr][oldrc].setIcon(null);
                Random random = new Random();
                arrayWM[oldrr][oldrc].setIcon(null);
                int rr = random.nextInt(3 - 0 + 1) + 0;
                int rc = random.nextInt(3 - 0 + 1) + 0;
                oldrr = rr;
                oldrc = rc;
                arrayWM[rr][rc].setIcon(new ImageIcon("img/one.jpg"));


                arrayWM[rr][rc].addMouseListener(act );
            }
        });
```

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: <face palm> You're creating a new instance of `MouseAdpater` each time the `Timer` is called, so calling `removeMouseListener(act)` has no effect because the label doesn't have that `MouseListener` registered with it

Answer (score 2):

Each time the `Timer` is triggered, you create ANOTHER instance of a `MouseAdapter` and attempt to remove this instance from the `JLabel`, but the label does not have that instance registered to it.  You then add ANOTHER instance of `MouseListener` to the label, compounding the number of `MouseListener`s which are registered to any one label at a time.

Instead, create a single instance of the `MouseAdapter` and re-use, maybe something like this...

```
Timer picTimer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {

    int oldrr = 0;
    int oldrc = 0;
    final int[] score = {0};
    MouseAdapter act = new MouseAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

            score[0]++;
            lblTimer.setText(String.valueOf(score[0]));

        }
    };

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        arrayWM[oldrr][oldrc].removeMouseListener(act);
        arrayWM[oldrr][oldrc].setIcon(null);
        Random random = new Random();
        arrayWM[oldrr][oldrc].setIcon(null);
        int rr = random.nextInt(3 - 0 + 1) + 0;
        int rc = random.nextInt(3 - 0 + 1) + 0;
        oldrr = rr;
        oldrc = rc;
        arrayWM[rr][rc].setIcon(new ImageIcon("img/one.jpg"));

        arrayWM[rr][rc].addMouseListener(act);
    }
});
```